# Excel: Returning Value from third column if three match

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have two excel spreadsheets, with a structure as following:

Sheet1

**A1-A1000 (Names):**
Doe, John
Example, Jane

**C1-C1000 (Birthdates):**
12-25-1990
1-01-2000

Sheet2

**B2-B1000 (Names):**
Doe, John
Matthews, Andy

**D2-D1000 (Birthdates):**
*Matching Birthdates to be populated here*

Essentially, I need to compare thousands of values in the two sheets, and if their rows they have matching names, I need to put the birthdate from the row of Sheet1 to the corresponding name  into the D column in Sheet2. Anyone have any idea of going about this?

Thank you for your help, I have no experience with excel so I'm new to all of this.

Comment: Given your data setup, you could probably just use a [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1): `=VLOOKUP(Sheet2!B2,Sheet1!$A:$C,3,FALSE)`

Comment: Try `=INDEX(Sheet1!$C$1:Sheet1!$C$1000, MATCH(Sheet2!$B$2,Sheet1!$A$2:Sheet1!$A$1000, 0))`

Comment: Do I have to do this for every single cell, or will this output everything into D2 for all the thousands of birthdates? Just want to make sure I'm asking my question right.

Comment: @JasonBourne see my answer below, just edited the reference to make it change as you drag the formula down.  As it is copied/dragged down the reference `$B2` will change to `$B3` and so on.

Comment: I have a total of 1500 columns though, is there a way to do it for every column, or it just copy and paste into each cell...?

Comment: yes as I said you simply Put the formula in D2, then copy,drag or fill down the column, it will update the reference needed.

Comment: here is a blog on how to fill a column with formulas: https://www.pryor.com/blog/copy-excel-formulas-down-to-fill-a-column/

Comment: Do you have any idea @ScottCraner why the matching values are showing up as a random number and not the source format of 58-Aug-56 or something?

Comment: It is a date, you just need to format the cell as you want the date to appear.  A date to Excel is the number of days since 1/1/1900.  so to excel today's date is 42810

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at the `vlookup` function. You can find documentation here: [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

I have put this into Sheet1 (with column B blank):

```
John        12/25/1990
Jane        1/1/2000
```

In Sheet2, I placed `John`, `Andy`, and `Jane` in A1, A2, and A3.

In B2, to the right of `John`, I placed:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$C$4,3,FALSE)
```

Let me explain. The A1 means I'm seeking `John` in A1 of Sheet2.  The

```
Sheet1!$A$1:$C$4
```

tells the function to look at Sheet1, columns A through C (and rows 1 through 4). The dollar signs are necessary to tell Excel to use absolute (rather than relative) references. (Relative references would make the whole thing shift in undesirable ways.) (You would want yours to go from `$A$1` to `$C$1000` if you have 1000 names and birthdays.)

The `3` means to return the third column, which in your case, is the birthday.

The `FALSE` means that you have to have an exact match.

I then copied down B1 to B2 and B3.

Here are the results:

```
John    12/25/1990
Andy    #N/A
Jane    1/1/2000
```

It found John and Jane, and returned their birthdates. It did not find Andy, and so it displays an #N/A.

(Following are edit 2, from comments in which the OP asked some branching questions.)

### Copying the formula, using Fill Down

Rather than Ctrl-C + Ctrl-V, there are keyboard shortcuts to copy the formula down a column. Click on B1 to highlight it. Then hold the shift key down and press the down arrow twice. Now B1, B2, and B3 are highlighted. Then press Ctrl-D to Fill Down the formula. If done correctly, one should have the same formula in B3 as in B1. You can reuse this same technique, but you can use Shift+PageDn ten times (and then Ctrl-D) to copy the formula 250 times.

### Formatting a column to be dates

Click on the column with the numbers, and change the format drop-down from General to Short Date. This will switch the formatting of the cell from e.g., `21567` (the internal Excel representation) to `1/17/1959`.

### Adding an error message

In the comments, the OP asked how to have an error message instead of the #N/A. One could wrap the `VLOOKUP` in another function, namely `IFNA`. For example,

```
 =IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$C$4,3,FALSE), "Lookup failure.")
```

would provide the date (if the name were found) or would say "Lookup failure."

Comment: I'm trying to work this out, but is this only a solution to copy and paste to individual cells? Because I have to do this for about 1500 values. Because you said "then I copied down B1 to B2 and B3. I have to do this for thousands of values.

Comment: Is the number 3 column you returned the one in between the 3 columns or the total number column in the whole sheet?

Comment: No, there are keyboard shortcuts to do this. Click on B1 to highlight it. Then hold the shift key down and press the down arrow twice. Now B1, B2, and B3 are highlighted. Then press Ctrl-D to Fill Down the formula. If done correctly, one should have the same formula in B3 as in B1. Use the same technique, but you can use Shift+PageDn ten times (and then Ctrl-D) to copy the formula 250 times. There is yet another shortcut, but please try these first.

Comment: The number 3 in `=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$C$4,3,FALSE)` means "if found, use the 3rd column of the found row"

Comment: Thank you very much, I've got a few to match!

My only issue is this. On the spreadsheets with the birthdate, the date is something in the format of 30-Aug-58.

However, when a match is found and it comes into the new column, a random number comes out like 21567, which doesn't correspond with the date :/

Comment: You're welcome! The date fix is an easy one. Click on the column with the numbers, and change the format drop-down from General to Short Date. This will switch from 21567 (the internal Excel representation) to 1/17/1959.

Comment: Massive help! Thank you very much!

Comment: I have to cross reference this with a few more sheets, so I'm going to use your function to set an error message type thing. Is there a way to only run a formula on something IF it has that error message (like do copy and pasting and only run if if the field is blank like "" or "none" rather than a date?)

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track but you have your columns in the wrong place.

The match is what you use to find the match, so it should be:

```
MATCH(Sheet2!$B2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$1000, 0)
```

Or you can use full column without detriment:

```
MATCH(Sheet2!$B2,Sheet1!$A:$A, 0)
```

Then Your index is the column that gets returned:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$C:$C,...)
```

So together

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$C:$C,MATCH(Sheet2!$B2,Sheet1!$A:$A, 0))
```

One note if the name is not found it will return an error, you can capture that error with `IFERROR` and return something else:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$C:$C,MATCH(Sheet2!$B2,Sheet1!$A:$A, 0)),"Name not Found")
```

Now if the name on sheet2 is not in sheet1 then it will return `Name not Found` instead of an error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have just confused you matches.

```
=Index(sheet1!C:C,match(sheet2!B:B,Sheet1!A:A,0))
```

Comment: The first statement in the match should be `sheet2!B2` not `sheet2!B:B`

Comment: You do not need to explicitly state the cell, as the match will work from the same row. I find this is less likely to get thrown out by user interference and sorting

Comment: @RhysWilliams you are correct, but it does require that the formula be put in the same row as the desired match.  It is akin to not stating the parent worksheet of a range in vba, if you only use the one sheet it works fine, but when multiple sheets are introduced it can get errant answers.  I would at least put the caveat in the answer that the formula will return the match of column B in the same row as the formula is entered, just in case some one in the future who has a slightly different setup comes along.

Comment: ah ok. I did not release this. thanks for the heads up